# Is there any harm in setting both internal and external encoding to utf-8 on windows?

Tags: ruby, windows, encoding, utf-8

I am writing a Ruby app on windows, and encountering some annoying encoding related issues. However, when i set both the internal and external default encodings to `utf-8` these problems disappear.

What do i have to worry about in doing this? might doing this come back to bite me later on?

Answer (score 0):

> might doing this come back to bite me later on

Yes.  Anytime you try to read a file that is not encoded in UTF-8 you will get bitten.  Your system has some locale settings that ruby reads to set your external default encoding.

Comment: Thanks, but in my case I am in control of every file that gets read and they are all UTF-8 - so i'm safe?